# My ubuntu (14.04.02 LTS) doen't recognize my graphic card

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, vga

I installed linux Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS 64 bit on my computer.
I have *sapphire radeon r7 265* graphics card and I tried to install the latest drivers following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) guide (Installing via the command line) :

Everything went fine and by using the command `fglrxinfo` I get this:

```
display: :0  screen: 0 OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R7 200 Series OpenGL version string: 4.3.12798 Compatibility Profile Context 13.35.1005
```

From the command `lspci | grep VGA` I get this:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn PRO [Radeon HD 7850]
```

and `sudo lshw -class video` provides this:

```
    *-display description: VGA compatible controller product: Pitcairn PRO [Radeon HD 7850] 
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] 
physical id: 0 
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0 version: 00 
width: 64 bits 
clock: 33MHz 
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=fglrx_pci 
latency=0 resources: irq:88      
memory:c0000000-cfffffff 
memory:fea00000-fea3ffff 
ioport:e000(size=256) 
memory:fea40000-fea5ffff
```

And from system info, under graphic it says `VESA: PITCAIRN`

I've even read that I may have to switch the graphics card from my bios, but I don't find any setting for it.

How should I proceed?

Comment: And what is the output of `sudo lshw -class video` ?

Comment: It appears that the latest stable version for your card can be found here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86 (the 32-bit drivers must be installed for the 64 bit drivers to function per AMD. The latest Beta driver is available here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx

Comment: This is what i get from that command



  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Pitcairn PRO [Radeon HD 7850]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:88 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:fea00000-fea3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea40000-fea5ffff

Comment: As we see only the single graphics card you reported in the lshw listing, proceed to check the links in my previous comment.

Comment: I've donwloaded the drivers from the  first link, i've put the files into the home folder. When i give the command "sudo sh ./......"  it says that it can't open the file

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the information to it. All I see is "sudo sh ./......" which isn't nearly enough for me to determine what went wrong.

Comment: Ok, i've manage to successfully install the latest beta drivers (AMD Catalyst™ 14.12 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver), i didn't get any errors from the terminal. The problem persist. Ubuntu keep telling me he is using the HD 7850 instead of my r7 265. From the preview commands i keep getting the same answers.

Comment: do you have 2 display adaptors in the system? your lshw output doesn't indicate that. "Pitcairn PRO [Radeon HD 7850]"

Comment: "A rose by any other name..." same card? Try here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

Comment: How can i check if i have more display adaptors?

(thanks for your help by the way)

Comment: Your question indicates the output of `sudo lshw -class video` which shows the one card. Please refer to the note in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

Answer the questions 1 through 4 and choose display results. Then download the appropriate packages. Install both the 32 bit and 64 bit drivers for your system as the chip manufacturer insists this is required.

Note: the Radeon R7 265 (codenamed PITCAIRN) is just a slightly overclocked version of the Radeon HD 7850

You may need some additional files:

open a terminal and issue these commands:
since you are running 14.04.2 and are affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1424491) which is posted as a status of in progress. You should add yourself to the list, letting the developers know that this bug effects you too.

The workaround that has been known to work is

`sudo apt-get install libcheese*`

`sudo apt-get install xorg-core`

then
`sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`

sources for this final bit.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266268&page=3
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266268&page=4
http://packages.ubuntu.com/eo/trusty/xorg-video-abi-15

Comment: If i choose linux x86 or linux x86_64 i'll get the same file that i've already installed before (AMD Catalyst™ 14.12 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver).
I tried the option ubuntu x86 instead. I downloaded all the 4 .deb packages, extracted them into the home folder, run the terminal and gave the command "sudo dpkg -i *.deb" to install all the files, but i got this error: "dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx-core:
 fglrx-core depends on dkms."  And i've already installed dkms package of course.

Comment: Editing answer.

Comment: I did everything you wrote without getting any errors.
In "additional drivers" i can see that i am "using video drivers fro the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx-updates (proprietary)".
From the other commands: "lspci | grep VGA" , "fglrxinfo" , and "sudo lshw -class video" i'm still gettin same results.